# Coverage of LLVM/Clang source code

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

I am building LLVM and Clang. What option should I pass in `cmake` to enable coverage of LLVM and Clang source code.
Note, I want to get the coverage of LLVM source code itself. For example, if I run `clang t.c`, I want to see which parts of LLVM have been run.

Comment: I want to profile `Clang` itself, no any other C program.

Comment: so profile clang while it is compiling your program.   A compiler is just another program.

Comment: The question is how to profile clang while it is compiling. In GCC there is `enable-coverage` option that should be passed to `configure`. What is the equivalent in LLVM/clang build?

Comment: "how to profile clang while it is compiling"  run a profiler on it while it's compiling your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `make ENABLE_COVERAGE=1` after 'cmake'